# Privilege levels

Tags: security

PacketTracer does not support the function of associating views with specific users, therefore I tried another approach.

My goal is to have two different users, one with privilege 15 and one with privilege 0. Privilege 0 user should only be able to use ping function and then logout.

I set it up accordingly:

```
username user1 privilege 0 secret cisco
username superuser privilege 15 secret cisco1

privilege exec level 0 ping

line console 0
login local
```

However when I login again and "show privilege" both users has level 15 and can perform all of the tasks. This is obviously a big security flaw. Am I missing something simple here? I also tried to adding a password to console 0, all to no avail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I entered the same configuration, and I got the same results. Then I added another user "user2" with privs 0. But I didn't specify and commands to use.

I then logged in as user1 and used ping without entering "enable" and the ping went through just fine. But when I logged in as user2, I couldn't use ping. From what I can tell, when a user uses "enable", it gives them 15 priv. The priv level you set when making that user is the level of privilege they have *without* using enable.

If you want to enforce these privs on these users, disable their use of the enable command.